# How to Reduce Running (for loop), Python

Tags: python, loops, pandas, time

1. Following Code is taking too much running time (more than 5min)
2. Is there any good ways to reduce running time.

   ```
   data.head() # more than 10 year data, Total iteration is around 4,500,000
                   Open      High       Low     Close  Volume  Adj Close  \
   Date                                                                    
   2012-07-02  125500.0  126500.0  124000.0  125000.0  118500  104996.59   
   2012-07-03  126500.0  130000.0  125500.0  129500.0  239400  108776.47   
   2012-07-04  130000.0  132500.0  128500.0  131000.0  180800  110036.43   
   2012-07-05  129500.0  131000.0  127500.0  128500.0  118600  107936.50   
   2012-07-06  128500.0  129000.0  126000.0  127000.0  149000  106676.54
   ```
3. My Code is

   ```
   import pandas as pd
   import numpy as np
   from pandas.io.data import DataReader
   import matplotlib.pylab as plt
   from datetime import datetime        

   def DataReading(code):
       start = datetime(2012,7,1)
       end = pd.to_datetime('today')
       data = DataReader(code,'yahoo',start=start,end=end) 
       data = data[data["Volume"] != 0]  
       return data

   data['Cut_Off'] = 0
   Cut_Pct = 0.85

   for i in range(len(data['Open'])):
       if i==0:
           pass
       for j in range(0,i):
           if data['Close'][j]/data['Close'][i-1]<=Cut_Pct:
              data['Cut_Off'][j] = 1 
              data['Cut_Off'][i] = 1 
           else
               pass
   ```
4. Above Code takes more than 5 min. 
   Of course, there are "elif" are following(I didn't write above code)
   I just tested above code.

Is there any good ways to reduce above code running time?

5. additional

   ```
       buying list is
       Open      High       Low     Close  Volume  Adj Close  \
    Date                                                                    
    2012-07-02  125500.0  126500.0  124000.0  125000.0  118500  104996.59   
    2012-07-03  126500.0  130000.0  125500.0  129500.0  239400  108776.47   
    2012-07-04  130000.0  132500.0  128500.0  131000.0  180800  110036.43   
    2012-07-05  129500.0  131000.0  127500.0  128500.0  118600  107936.50   
    2012-07-06  128500.0  129000.0  126000.0  127000.0  149000  106676.54   
    2012-07-09  127000.0  133000.0  126500.0  131500.0  207500  110456.41   
    2012-07-10  131500.0  135000.0  130500.0  133000.0  240800  111716.37   
    2012-07-11  133500.0  136500.0  132500.0  136500.0  223800  114656.28   
    for exam, i bought 10 ea at 2012-07-02 with 125,500, and as times goes 
    daily, if the close price drop under 85% of buying price(125,500) then i         
    will sell out 10ea with 85% of buying price. 
    for reducing running time, i made buying list also(i didnt show in here)
    but it also take more than 2 min with using for loop.
   ```

Comment: Can you post a desired output for the specified sample DF? Otherwise it's hard to guess what are you trying to do...

Comment: My desire output is

Comment: My desire output is. For exam. 1. Buy stock 1st feb, 2ea. 1 usd. 2nd buy 3rd march 3ea 1.5 usd.  And then calculate profit ratio every day from april if the price drop 0.85 from buying price then sell out. For exam there are no price under 0.85 from 1.5 usd and 1 usd at april. Then no action but 1st may it drop 1.275 then i will sell out 3ea of 1.5 usd. But still hold 2ea of 1usd. And some times goes it drop 0.85 usd then i will sell out 2ea . 1usd. Above code is for finding this stock.

Comment: Have you profiled your code?

Comment: @Rogalski i just showed price and volume data. But my data have buying column. This column have 0 and 1. 1 means i bought some quantity.

Comment: @Rogalski i wanna examine each bought price profit ratio every day and if it drop under 85%. Then sell out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than iterating over the 4.5MM rows in your data, use pandas' built-in indexing features. I've re-written the loop at the end of your code as below:

```
data.loc[data.Close/data.Close.shift(1) <= Cut_Pct,'Cut_Off'] = 1
```

.loc locates rows that meet the criteria in the first argument. .shift shifts the rows up or down depending on the argument passed.

Comment: i am wondering if i use .loc then what you advised, then does it work similar with iteration?  i wanna calculate profit ratio what i bought in the past at everyday. the code what you commented seem to not work everyday. @Moe